# Securing Only API Access Using OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect

Tags: c#, rest, openid, owin, oauth-2.0

I've got a .NET web API that I'm trying to secure and want to allow a client application (angularJs) to make calls to it once it is authorized through the identity server. I want this authorization to be completely separate from user authentication/authorization. I don't want there to be any user interaction.

What have I missed?

Comment: How have you implmented oauth2? Using JWT tokens?

Comment: Yes. I've got oauth2 with openid connect sitting on top of it on the identity server. I thought the implicit flow would work here but it still wants actual user credentials.

Comment: Not enough info to help you